# Delete button hides behind the cell on iPad mini (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview, ipad-mini

I have updated my App for iOS 7.1 support. My app supports only iPad devices - it runs fine on iPad 2, 3 and 4 but on iPad mini I am facing a strange issue:

On editing a cell when user tries to delete the cell, Delete button hides behind the cell.

Look at the below image red button is hidden:

[image]

Do I need any additional handling for iPad mini?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything different for just an iPad Mini... What version of iOS is the iPad 2/3/4 running? 7.1?

Comment: And the first iPad mini is non-retina

Comment: please post more details about cell, is from xib or you make it in code

Comment: Device versions are  iPad 2 GSM (iOS 7.1),iPad 3 (iOS 7.0.4), iPad 4(iOS 7.1 and iOS 6.1.3)  amd iPad mini GSM (iOS 7.0.2)

Comment: I am adding background image in tableview cell             UIImageView *backView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:@"Cell_backGroundImage"];
    cell.backgroundView = backView;

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, you added subviews to this cell like

```
[cell addSubview:SomeCoolView];
```

instead of use contentView

```
[cell.contentView:addSubview:SomeCoolView];
```

from apple docs:

contentView
Returns the content view of the cell object. (read-only)

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIView *contentView
```

**Discussion**

*The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.*

[UITableViewCell Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView)